# ChromeOS CLI terminal app?

Tags: terminal, command-line, google-chrome-os

I assume ChromeOS has a CLI terminal application. Does it open up in a browser tab, or is it an independent window? Does anyone have any screenshots handy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a Chromebook Samsung Series 5. CTRL-ALT-T provides a "crosh" terminal but there is no shell available. SSH works in limited fashion, and ssh keys must be generated elsewhere and on attached media. "ssh" opens the ssh subsystem, and from there you use "key" to select the identity file. Then you use "host" to specify the system to connect to, and "connect" to ssh to it. You can also forward ports, but it will only allow binding of local ports 8000-8999 inclusive.

Update: Full tomfoolery possible in developer mode: http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/samsung-series-5-chromebook

It seems most Chromebook devices will have this "not easily accessible" switch to turn on the full capabilities.

Answer (score 9):

It's an independent window and can be opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: Using that, I can get to a virtual terminal, but I can't even run "ls" from it.  It only seems to support 15 commands, including top but not ps or even ls or cd.

Answer (score 6):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and then type `shell`. It will give you a real shell with bash.

Comment: The `shell` command only works in Developer Mode.